# Talk about continuity of discrete data

Tags: geometry, data-analysis, continuity

It is not difficult to say the continuity of the simple function.

It is also not difficult to say the continuity of the geometry.

For example, we can say the following function is $C^0$ continuous.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x  & \mbox{if }x \ge 0, \\ 0 &\text{if }x < 0\end{cases}.$$

We can say the corner in the following geometry is $C^0$ continuous
[image]

**But how can we decide the continuity of discrete data**?
For example, I think it should be $C^{-1}$ continuous.
[image]
But someone will say they can find a function that interpolates those point and guarantee the function to be $C^1$ continuous or even $C^\infty$ continuous

Then I have two questions:

1. Is there any definition that will tell: if the discrete data likes that, it is $C^{-1}$ continuous.
2. If I get the function that interpolates those points and is $C^1$ continuous or even $C^\infty$ continuous, I guess it will give lines which have very large oscillations. Based on the oscillations, can we say those data are not $C^1$ continuous or even $C^\infty$ continuous?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Basically, you can't without additional assumptions on the putative interpolating function. I guess you could bound certain quantitative measures of "how continuous" the function is, like the size of Lipshitz constant or the magnitude of the high-frequency fourier modes .

Comment: @MikeHawk, Thank you, I read both ways and I think it works.